Quota Limits for GMail batchModify
The GMail API has a batchModify method, which allows you to assign or remove labels from a large number of messages at one time.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/batchModify
However -- the quota units for this method are not mentioned on the Usage limits page
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota
What are the quota units for this method?  Or, if there aren't any (how do you know this?), what are the limitations on this method (other than the 1000 IDs listen in the above docs)?

Batching is restricted by the same quote limits as single calls.    If anything batching is worse as you are more likely to get hit for flooding with batching then not
